# IBM Assembler table search

Tags: assembly, mainframe

I'm trying to load the address of a table entry into a register and then compare the first 2 positions of the table entry to a field in the input file and do further processing from there.

However, I can't seem to load the address of the table entry into the register successfully, like my textbook and different websites show. I'm not sure where to go from here, any direction would be helpful. Anything I try goes into an infinite loop, or just displays the NOTFOUND message.

Below are parts of the code.

```
GETREC   EQU   *                              
     GET   TAPEIN,MHOMEOWN                                     
     AP    INCOUNT,=P'1'                        
     AP    CNT100,=P'1'                         
     CP    CNT100,=P'100'                 
     BNE   GETREC                
     PUT   DISKOUT,MHOMEOWN      
     BAL   R10,MNPRCS          
     AP    OTCOUNT,=P'1'
     ZAP   CNT100,=P'0' 
     B     GETREC       
     SPACE 1            
.....

NOTFOUND EQU   *                                            
     MVC   P+10(40),=CL40'PAR XX - NOT FOUND IN PARDTAB'
     MVC   P+14(2),MPARISH                              
     BAL   R8,PRINT                                     
     DC    X'FFFF'                                      
     EJECT                                              

MNPRCS   EQU   *                                            
     LA    R8,PARDTAB                                   
     CLC   MPARISH,0(R8)                                
     BE    COUNT                                        
     BNE   NOTFOUND                                     
     LA    R8,3(R8)                                     
     B     MNPRCS                                       

 table excerpt:
 PARDTAB  EQU   *              
      DC    CL2'01',CL1'3' 
      DC    CL2'03',CL1'2' 
      DC    CL2'04',CL1'5'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my own question. The second LA instruction in the MNPRCS loop is supposed to advance to the next line in the table in order to find a match. However, when I loop back to start the process the first LA instruction loads the table from the beginning again. So it was causing and endless loop. I changed my code to the following:

```
MNLOAD   EQU   *              
         LA    R8,PARDTAB     
MNPRCS   CLC   0(2,R8),MPARISH
         BE    COUNT          
         CLC   0(2,R8),=C'..' 
         BE    NOTFOUND       
         LA    R8,3(R8)       
         B     MNPRCS
```